# Working on a python problem trying to guess a randomly generated number im generally new to python and would appreciate some advice

Tags: python, if-statement, random, input, while-loop

having trouble when it trys comparing the input and the random integer

```
import random
target = random.randint(1,100)
counter = 0
print(target)
print(int(input('Guess an integer between 1 and 100 ')))
guess = input
while guess != target():
    if guess > target():
        print("Guess is to high")
    elif guess < target():
        print("Guess was to low")
    counter = counter + 1
    print(int(input('Guess an integer between 1 and 100 ')))
    
print("Correct it took you " + str(counter) + " guesses to get the correct number")
```

i tried changing the variable names starting from scratch several times googled tons of stuff but im lost and and confused and need an answer so please if you understand my problem id appreciate some advice

Comment: The variable `target` in your code is an `integer`. It is not callable. Change that first

Answer (score 1):

You have several issues with your code:

1. You have `print(int(input('Guess an integer between 1 and 100 ')))` followed by `guess = input`. You are not assigning to `guess` what was entered but rather setting it to refer to a function.
2. In several places you have `target()`. But target is of type `int`, not a function, and you cannot call it as if it were a function.
3. After a user enters a guess, it narrow downs the range of legal guess and therefore your prompt should change accordingly.
4. You should check for guess outside the legal range.

```py
import random

target = random.randint(1,100)
low = 1
high = 100

counter = 0
while True:
    guess = int(input(f'Guess an integer between {low} and {high}: '))
    if guess == target:
        break
    if not low <= guess <= high:
        print('Your guess is outside the legal range of guesses.')
    elif guess > target:
        print("Guess is to high.")
        high = guess - 1
    else:
        print("Guess was to low.")
        low = guess + 1
    counter = counter + 1

print("Correct! It took you", counter, "guesses to get the correct number.")
```

Answer (score 1):

Problems:

1. `print(int(input('Guess an integer between 1 and 100 ')))` is reading a value, converting it to `int`, printing it, then throwing it away so your guesses are never used
2. `guess = input` is assigning the function `input` to `guess` (which is useless, and actively harmful when you get to comparing to `target`, since a function and an `int` are not orderable relative to one another); since you never reassign it, this never changes
3. `target` should never be called (replace every use of `target()` with `target`), it's an `int`, not a callable function
4. Minor: If possible, it's nicer to avoid duplicating code; the Python 3.8+ walrus operator (`:=`) lets you both read a value and compare in the `while` conditional, which avoids the need to double the `input` code

Fixing all of these gets:

```
import random
target = random.randint(1,100)
print(target)
counter = 1  # Start counter at 1, since we can't increment it if the input actually matches
# Walrus allows reading, assigning, and testing in a single line
while (guess := int(input('Guess an integer between 1 and 100 '))) != target:
    if guess > target:
        print("Guess is too high")  # sp fix
    elif guess < target:
        print("Guess was too low")  # sp fix
    counter += 1  # Save a little typing by using counter += 1 instead of counter = counter + 1

 # f-string saves manual string conversion and piecemeal concatenation
 print(f"Correct it took you {counter} guesses to get the correct number")
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added new changes, get rid of # while guess != target

```
import random
target = random.randint(1,100)
counter = 0
print(target)
check=False
while not check:
   guess = int(input('Guess an integer between 1 and 100 '))

   if guess > target:
    print("Guess is to high")
   elif guess < target:
    print("Guess was to low")
   else:
    check = True
    break
   counter = counter + 1
  
  
print("Correct it took you " + str(counter) + " guesses to get the correct number")enter code here
```

Comment: You have a variable `check` that is useless because after you set `check = True` you issue a `break` statement to exit the loop and `check` will never even be checked again. You might as well replace `while not check:` with `while True:`. By the way, `check` is a strange name for the variable because as long as it is `False` you actually want to get new guesses and **check** them.

Comment: yeah make sense...but thought the var `check` would provide more context to understand the code.

Answer (score -1):

Try these changes,

```
import random
target = random.randint(1,100)
counter = 0
print(target)
guess = int(input('Guess an integer between 1 and 100 '))
while guess != target:
   if guess > target:
     print("Guess is to high")
   elif guess < target:
     print("Guess was to low")
counter = counter + 1


print("Correct it took you " + str(counter) + " guesses to get the correct number")
```

Comment: While this did fix one issue im now struggling to complete the assignments goal to use a while loop to create a random number and have the ability to guess multiple times until you have found the correct answer now it is just repeating if the guess was to low or high and not asking you to guess again

Comment: You only input a guess once and you are only incrementing counter once. If the guess is not correct you go into an infinite loop. Do you not test your code?

Comment: @Booboo true...modified the code...thank you for letting me know

Comment: @Priya You may have modified it, but did you save it?

Answer (score -1):

You do not to `print` when you ask for an `input` value, as that function will take care of printing the text you give it. You're also not updating `guess` after a new request. Try this instead:

```
import random                                                                                           
target = random.randint(1,100)                                                                          
                                                                                                        
counter = 0                                                                                             
print(target)                                                                                           
                                                                                                        
guess = int(input('Guess an integer between 1 and 100 '))                                               
while guess != target:                                                                                  
    if guess > target:                                                                                  
        print("Guess is to high")                                                                       
    elif guess < target:                                                                                
        print("Guess was to low")                                                                       
    counter = counter + 1                                                                               
    guess = int(input('Guess an integer between 1 and 100 '))                                           
                                                                                                        
print("Correct it took you " + str(counter) + " guesses to get the correct number")
```

Comment: You are putting out an incorrect number of guesses.